# How to get values with respact to angle

Tags: javascript, php

Angle 0 to 180 deg. i want the value in between them, like:

```
Angle 0deg then value = -10
Angle 90deg then value = 0
Angle 180deg then value = 10
```

values vary in between -10 to 10.

Comment: You left out `Angle 270deg then value = -0`!

Comment: Agreed, it's shouldn't be tagged trigo.

Comment: I found the answer of my question given by @Samy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getValue(angle) {
    return Math.round(angle / 180 * 20 - 10);
}
```

It's a simple linear interpolation. You're going from [0:180] to [-10:10]. So here are the steps:

- Divide your angle by 180 to make it in the range [0:1] (normalize).
- Multiply by 20, which is the width of your target range. You get [0:20].
- Subtract 10 to shift your range by 10 and have it centered at 0. You get [-10:10]

You can get rid of `Math.round` if you want decimal values.

Comment: Agreed. Asked for tag removal.

Comment: @user3073543 Don't just thank Samy. You should upvote his answer or if his answer adequately answered your question and you don't see any other answer as superior then you accept his answer with the check mark under the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: @DutGRIFF thanks for mentioning ;) Indeed user3073543 if the answer answers your question, you should accept it, thus making it available to others with the same problem.